# Lua OR find and Replace

Tags: lua

My `LaTeX-out.tex`  TeX Code is (single line):

```
\begin{align*}\alpha + \beta = \gamma\end{align*} Some text here. \begin{align*}\sum^{k}_{i=1} \iota \end{align*} and so on the text. \begin{thebibliography}{000}\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}{Aasi J et al LIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations 2014 Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo gravitational-wave detectors.} \bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}{Abbott B P et al LIGO and Virgo Collaborations 2016 Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger GW150914 L22} \bibitem{cqgab7bbabib3}{Abbott B P et al LIGO and Virgo Scientific Collaboration 2016 Search for transient gravitational waves in coincidence with short duration radio transients during 2007–2013}. \bibitem{cqgab7bbabib4}{Abbott B P et al The LIGO Scientific and Virgo Collaborations 2018 GWTC-1: a gravitational-wave transient catalog of compact binary.}
```

My `Lua Code` is (i would like enter(\n) before \begin and enter(\n) before \bibitem):

```
local file = io.open("LaTeX-out.tex")
local fileedited = io.open("LaTeX-Updated.tex", "w")
local content = file:read "*a"
file:close()
contentmodified = string.gsub(content, [[\begin]], [[\n\begin]])
contentmodified = string.gsub(content, [[\end]], [[\n\end]])
contentmodified = string.gsub(content, [[\bibitem]], [[\n\bibitem]])
contentmodified = string.gsub(content, [[(\begin or \end)]], [[\n%1]])--it's not working **or**
fileedited:write(contentmodified)
fileedited:close()
```

But it's taking only final find and replace only (like **\bibitem**) and ignoring **\begin** and **\end**. How do solve this?

Comment: do you want to add a newline or literally the two characters `\n` ?  `[[\n\bibitem]]`  note `\n` and `\b` have the same level of quoting here,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have need a newline and i'm not clear about **\n and \b have the same level of quoting**

Comment: I mean surely you can see if `\b` in `\begin` means literally `\b` then the `\n` in the same string means literally `\n` not a newline. See the version in my answer where `\n` and `\b` are quoted differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `"` not `[[` so that `\n` means newline, and you need to apply your later replacements to the `contentmodified` result of the earlier changes, not to the original string.

```
local file = io.open("LaTeX-out.tex")
local fileedited = io.open("LaTeX-Updated.tex", "w")
local content = file:read "*a"
file:close()
contentmodified = string.gsub(content, [[\begin]], "\n\\begin")
contentmodified = string.gsub(contentmodified, [[\end]], "\n\\end")
contentmodified = string.gsub(contentmodified, [[\bibitem]], "\n\\bibitem")
fileedited:write(contentmodified)
fileedited:close()
```

produces

```
\begin{align*}\alpha + \beta = \gamma
\end{align*} Some text here. 
\begin{align*}\sum^{k}_{i=1} \iota 
\end{align*} and so on the text. 
\begin{thebibliography}{000}
\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib1}{Aasi J et al LIGO Scientific and VIRGO Collaborations 2014 Constraints on cosmic strings from the LIGO-Virgo gravitational-wave detectors.} 
\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib2}{Abbott B P et al LIGO and Virgo Collaborations 2016 Astrophysical implications of the binary black hole merger GW150914 L22} 
\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib3}{Abbott B P et al LIGO and Virgo Scientific Collaboration 2016 Search for transient gravitational waves in coincidence with short duration radio transients during 2007–2013}. 
\bibitem{cqgab7bbabib4}{Abbott B P et al The LIGO Scientific and Virgo Collaborations 2018 GWTC-1: a gravitational-wave transient catalog of compact binary.}
```

Comment: How to do `or` **[[(\begin or \end)]], "\n%1"** it's not working.

Comment: @Balaji why do you need that? `[[(\begin or \end)]]` is the literal string `\begin or \end` which does not occur here.

Comment: How to do Lua `or` statement. I have found (A or B) in the Lua Tutorials. But that's not working. Any example/sample link?

Comment: or is a Lua boolean operator not part of the pattern syntax for string searching.